# ADF binding of data control method which returns map<String,String>

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a data control method whose return type is Map

I want to bind this return type to a SelectOneChoice UI component such that display text  for select item should be Map.value and select item value should be Map.key .

Is it possible to acheive

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend :
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2427671

Or you can make an attribute of your Map, make a getter for it. Then you will be able to
drag your attribute on your page > select one > select one choice